# How to see if bug is still present, if it doesn't consistently manifest visibly?

Tags: c++, debugging, crash, qml, valgrind

I have a crash in my C++/QML app. The stacktrace from the core dump is not enlightening, so I'm using plan B: iteratively remove stuff from the app until the crash stops happening (a.k.a. producing a minimal testcase). The problem is that, to see if the bug is still present, I need to rerun the app up to 3-4 times until I finally hit the crash. And that takes time. **What would be a faster way to see if the bug is still present?**

I was thinking that if I run the app in one of valgrind's tools (probably Memcheck, Helgrind, DRD), I may get reports of the bug more consistently. I just tried Memcheck but it made the app start up really slowly, so that's not an improvement.

I'm developing on Linux.

Comment: Unit test the hell out of your application, for a start

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: I've been told that unit-testing GUI code is usually unproductive. And my job is to write GUI code.

Comment: Try to run the app under Valgrind. You may get Valgrind errors every time you run the app regardless of whether it crashes or not.

Comment: @ks1322: Which valgrind subtool? There are several

Comment: I would start with Memcheck (default one).

Comment: Can you trace the error by running the program in debug and exploring the call stack?

Comment: @AMA: I've explored the call stack anyway, without running in a debugger, and have found it to be worthless, as the only frames it lists are (a) in Qt code and (b) question marks. When running the problem in gdb, the crash never occurs, so that's out.

Comment: Did you try building in release with debug information enabled?

Comment: I would also start with memcheck. If that is clean, move on to Helgrind/DRD. Alternatively consider sanitizers with GCC or clang.

Comment: @AMA: Ok, I tried, but still on the first run the app didn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to hit a break point without having to do several test runs. I'm also assuming you know what causes the crash, but it just doesn't crash consistently.

You could create a new main method that invokes the root class/classes in your application and invoke the same functions that a user would do to cause the crash. You could iterate this until the crash happens (i.e. just tear everything down and do it again and again) or use threads to help and brute force cause the crash. I've done this to quickly force sporadic crashes in programs (I'm not going to pretend it's good practice though, but might help if there are no better suggestions).

Comment: Thanks. *"I'm assuming you want to hit a break point..."* - no, not a breakpoint. A crash. *"I'm also assuming you know what causes the crash, but it just doesn't crash consistently."* - I know **part** of what causes it, but still I need to iteratively strip down the app to figure out what other parts of the code act as enablers for the crash. And that means I want the bug to quickly "pop" every time. *"use threads to help and brute force cause the crash"* - that would not tell me what parts of the original code are causing the crash though.